# Use of canonical homomorphism in 1st Ring Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

I’m concerned about a particular part of the proof:
Why do most proofs of this theorem involve the canonical homomorphism. What does that add to the proof? (Nothing from what I can see.)
What’s wrong in just showing that there is a well-defined isomorphism, namely $\Phi : R/ker\phi \rightarrow im\phi$ defined by $[r]\mapsto \phi(r)$.

I know how to prove this theorem. I’m just interested in the purpose of people introducting the canonical homomorphism.

Comment: Which canonical homomorphism are you referring to?  The quotient map $R \to R/\ker\phi$ given by $r \mapsto [r]$?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1):

One reason to explicitly use the canonical homomorphisms in the various isomorphism theorems is that we can then interpret the results using the language of [commutative diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram).

Personally, this abstraction first became important in homological algebra.  I recall at least one proof which was completely unwieldy if you tried to follow how to define a map element-wise, but became almost trivial if you rewrote the map as a composition of natural maps coming from commutative diagrams (e.g. [snake lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma), [five lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma), or more generally limits/colimit diagrams, etc.).